# C++ inline single caller functions?

Tags: c++

In C, GCC will automatically inline all the static functions with a single caller. I am not sure how to achieve the same thing in CPP.

In the example above, foo() is private and it's only called by bar. foo() is too big to be placed in the .h file. How do I make foo() inlined?

```
class A
{
 private:
   void foo();
   void bar();
}

void A::foo() {
   // do something here
}
void A::bar() {
   foo();
}
```

Comment: With the `inline` keyword
or
By placing the `foo` code in the header file.

Comment: @Pierre The inline keyword has little effect on whether something is actually inlined in modern compilers.

Comment: `A::foo()` isn't a static function in this code, it's visible to all units. To replicate your C behaviour maybe you could actually use a static function (a function only declared within the .cpp file, that is, not a static class member)

Comment: _"In C, GCC will automatically inline all the static functions with a single caller."_ Really?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can only inline if it can see the function body when it is compiling the call site.

If you put the definitions of both `foo` and `bar` in the same source file then you give the compiler the best opportunity to inline `foo`.

Of course this may not actually make much difference to performance, depending on exactly what is in `foo` and `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

**GCC may even inline the method automatically** in this situation even without `inline`. Whether it will or will not is based on heuristics in the optimizers and therefore unpredictable, but if the function is large it probably won't.

You can place an inline directive on either the declaration of `foo()` in the class or on its definition in the impl.cpp. Per section 9.3 of C++ standard either will suffice. But GCC may not actually inline the function anyway, so it's useful only as a weak hint and/or documentation.

Both in C and C++, with or without `inline`, GCC will not inline anything unless optimization is enabled. The only way to force it is to use [Danny_ds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3447508), but it's not necessarily a good idea to do this. Optimizers are really good at knowing whether it's beneficial, and a simple function call can actually be extremely low overhead on modern CPUs. So it could be a little like "premature-optimization" to worry about it.

```
// header.h
class A
{
 private:
   /*inline*/ void foo(); // inline could be here
   void bar();
};

// impl.cpp

inline void A::foo() {
   // do something here
}

void A::bar() {
   foo();
}
```

You don't have to put the definition of `foo()` in the header file only because as you have stated it is used only by `bar()`. If it was a public method that could be called in other units, you would need to put the definition in the header and then must to mark it `inline` so that it changes the linkage and it is not an error to be multiply defined.

This last situation is really the only reason to use the `inline` keyword (comes up a lot in template code), otherwise it would probably be better to just let the optimizer figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I understand the "inline" keyword trick. In the case I am playing with, both bar() and foo() are big functions. So even with "inline" keyword, no inline was done. And I don't want to use "always_inline" attribute. I hope GCC can figure out foo has a single caller (within the same file) and thus should be inlined automatically. I understand in C++, detecting  single caller function is harder because a private function can be called by  methods in other files.

Comment: So, can I conclude that there's no such thing as "automatically inline single caller member functions" in c++? That will add some concerns about breaking big functions into smaller ones (since I am working on some performance sensitive code).

Comment: @yacc45 No, as long as you have the optimizer on, it will do the same thing it does in C: GCC will use heuristics to figure out what it wants to inline automatically whether or not you specify inline.

Comment: @yacc45 Have you tried -Winline? Also, are you checking the generated assembly at the call site to see if was inlined or not? Because the definition can't be file static, you are right - GCC can't know that nobody else might call the function. So I'd expect it to emit a function named `foo()`, even when it successfully inlines it at the call site in `bar()`.

Comment: @yacc45 I have just played with `-Winline` and `-finline-limit=n`, on a recent GCC (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). They seem to do what they are supposed to for me. If -Winline says that the size is the problem when it doesn't inline, perhaps you can increase the limit. Sadly, `-finline-functions-called-once` which is exactly what you are wanting is only for static functions but not members, even private ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `inline` keyword, or when optimisations are off, use:

```
__attribute__((always_inline))
```

> GCC does not inline any functions when not optimizing unless you
>   specify the ‘always_inline’ attribute for the function, like this:
>
> ```
>  /* Prototype.  */
>  inline void foo (const char) __attribute__((always_inline));
> ```

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html